# What happens to the symbol table once the object code is created and linked?

Tags: linker, compiler-construction, symbol-table

What happens to the symbol table once the object code is created and linked? Also how does a symbol table store parameters passing information specially when the called function is part of another library

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It disappears along with the compiler process that contains it. A form of it may be written into the object code as debug information.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to the symbol table once the object code is created and linked?

If requested, it is used as a basis for building a program database that can be used for debugging.

Otherwise it is usually disposed of.

> Also how does a symbol table store parameters passing information specially when the called function is part of another library

Generally, there is no difference in what information the compiler requires in order to generate a call to an external versus an internal function/method. The compilers that I am familiar with all store the parameters in the exact same way regardless of whether the implementation is internal or external.

Comment: "If requested, it is used as a basis for building a program database that can be used for debugging.
Otherwise it is usually disposed of." Then how are unresolved symbols/function calls identified and resolved during dynamic linking specially in case of shared libraries.

Comment: Shared libraries usually have a small embedded symbol table built for this very purpose.